# Viewbag id returns no data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, viewbag

This is the start of my index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<UsageReportViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UsageReport";
}

<h2>UsageItem</h2>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("Index")
.DataSource(data => data
.Ajax()
.Read(read => read.Action("GetUsageItems", "UsageReport", new { id = ViewBag.usageReportId }))
.Model(model => model.Id(m => m.Id))
```

^ Index:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    return View();
}
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    ViewBag.usageReportId = id;
    return View();
}
public ActionResult Get([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var GetFile = UsageReportSelection();
    return Json(GetFile.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
public ActionResult GetUsageItems([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    int id = ViewBag.usageReportId; // <--
    var GetFile = UsageReportItems(id);
    return Json(GetFile.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The int id from method GetUsageItems is returning "0". I need this to pass through some data like the public ActionResult index is doing with the Get method. I know I am doing something wrong just not sure what.

Comment: Where do you set the value of ViewBag.usageReportId??

Comment: @JCM put it in the code

Comment: You're showing us where you set the ViewBag.Title, not ViewBag.usageReportId.  Are you setting it on the page where GetUsageItems is being called?

Comment: @DanOrlovsky It's in my Details Actionresult.

Comment: @SennerP Thank you for the edit.  And you're sure your application gets to the Details controller method with a good Id before it gets to your GetUsageItems controller method?

Comment: @DanOrlovsky Int Id = 1;  ViewBag.usageReportId = null; so the int Id is right.

Comment: I think because you're using it between different controllers, the ViewBag object is being disposed of with the controller base.  It's not a Static object.

Comment: You're using ViewBag.usageReportId on the Index view. You should set value for it in the Index action.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get the value of `ViewBag.usageReportId` the way you are trying to get it. The ViewBag value you are passing `read => read.Action` method would come as extra parameter to the Action method at the server side.

So you have two ways to access this values at the controller action method.

One - Change controller action method to have extra parameter as following.

```
public ActionResult GetUsageItems([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int id)
{
    var GetFile = UsageReportItems(id);

    return Json(GetFile.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Follow https://www.telerik.com/forums/pass-additional-parameters-to-read-ajax-datasource-method---mvc to understand the example.

Two - Access the `id` from QueryString parameters.

```
public ActionResult GetUsageItems([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryStrings["id"]);
    var GetFile = UsageReportItems(id);
    return Json(GetFile.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This should help you resolve your issue.